# Email users on node creation based on location

Tags: location

I have location module install, which are referenced on both user and node (type: property). When a node (property type) is created, I need to email all users who have same location of node what created. At lest match with City/Zipcode field for the node.

Is it possible with rule? I do don't know coding. So your help is only hope for solve this problem.

Thank You.

Comment: As far as I know yes, it is possible with rules. But if you refuse to read the docs and experiment a bit before asking, I'm not going to do that either.

Comment: I am watching "Learn the Rules framework" by Nodeone.se. I trying to do it myself But can't figure it out. That's why I asked here. I would appreciate it if you can help me with this. Thanks.